# How to install ffmpeg without root?

Tags: video, music, installation, build, install-from-source

I want to install ffmpeg, however it seems that its impossible without root. there are sources, but I have to compile it somehow. how to compile it? I just need ffmpeg "exec".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use source package. Read [this](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aOneiric#Installing_a_package_from_source)

However, as an alternative you can always try to download the binary package, uncompress the .deb package in your home directory and append `$HOME/bin` and `$HOME/usr/bin` to `PATH` variable and `$HOME/lib` and `$HOME/usr/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

If you manually unpack binary packages, you need to resolve missing dependencies by your self (unpack also all required libraries).

Another option is to manually compile (`./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`) each library and ffmpeg from tar.gz packages.

Good luck.